# Convert HTML output into a plain text using php

Tags: php, html, plaintext

I'm trying to convert my sample HTML output into a plain text but I don't know how. I  use file_get_contents but the page which I'm trying to convert returns most like the same.

```
$raw = "http://localhost/guestbook/profiles.php";
$file_converted = file_get_contents($raw);
echo $file_converted;
```

profiles.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Profiles - GuestBook</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
<body>
    <!-- Some Divs -->
    <div id="profile-wrapper">
        <h2>Profile</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td><td> John Dela Cruz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Age:</td><td>15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Location:</td><td> SomewhereIn, Asia</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, I trying to echo out something like this (plain text, no styles)

```
Profile
Name: John Dela Cruz
Age: 15
Location: SomewhereIn, Asia
```

but i don't know how. :-( . Please help me guys , thank you in advance.

EDIT: Since i am only after of the content of the page, no matter if it's styled or just a plain text , is there a way to select only (see code below) using file_get_contents() ?

```
 <h2>Profile</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td><td> John Dela Cruz</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Age:</td><td>15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Location:</td><td> SomewhereIn, Asia</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response Sergej Jevsejev, josnidhin, and Jonathan Rich. Much aprreciated. :-)

Comment: Note that people saying to use `strip_tags` Don't fully understand it or are being careless.  It will leave your title intact, as well as any inline stylesheets or JavaScript.  You don't have any of the latter, but you do have a title. . .

Comment: i use strip_tags, though it takes off html tags but it returns to an undesirable output e.g. { font: bold 11px Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #045877; padding: 15px 0 0 12px; text-decoration: none; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }

Comment: maybe using strip_tags will surely answer the title of my question, as what i have seen, it's a plain text but using strip_tags doesn't help me to return desirable output.

Comment: use strip_tags or if you need plain text with html tags then: http://browse-tutorials.com/snippet/convert-text-or-html-plain-text-php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use php [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

If strip_tags is not working for then maybe you can use regex to extract the info you want.

Try using PHP [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with `/(<td>.*?<\/td>)/` as the pattern

Comment: Exactly, and if you do not need white spaces or other symbols (chars), refer to [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Comment: This is not `exactly`.  It will leave his title in the plain-text.

Comment: i use strip_tags, though it takes off html tags but it returns to an undesirable output e.g. { font: bold 11px Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #045877; padding: 15px 0 0 12px; text-decoration: none; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at simplexml_load_file():

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

It will allow you to load the HTML data into an object (SimpleXMLElement) and traverse that object like a tree.

Comment: If you add an example for him, this would be the best answer.  Right now it's too ambiguous to a beginner.

Comment: sorry, don't know to use xml load file

Comment: http://us.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php The basic usage is very simple. Do you have experience with PHP object interfaces?

Comment: @Jonathan Rich : nope, i'm just a newbie in Php , sorry for that sir

Comment: That's fine. Take a look at the example I pasted and see what you can come up with.

Answer (score 1):

try to use PHP function strip_tags

Comment: i use strip_tags, though it takes off html tags but it returns to an undesirable output e.g. { font: bold 11px Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #045877; padding: 15px 0 0 12px; text-decoration: none; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }

Answer (score 1):

try this one,

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("your_file");
preg_match_all('|<div[^>]*?>(.*?)</div>|si',$data, $result);
print_r($result[0][0]);
?>
```

I have try this one, and it seems work for me, for you too i hope

Comment: Hello Sir, what to put on the data varialble ?

Comment: just add `http://localhost/guestbook/profiles.php` to your variable, and then for `print_r()` you can use `foreach()` or something like that

Comment: Don’t [parse HTML with a regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/55965).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#100995) php function for this. Browse through the comments in the php manual page of the strip_tags function to see how you can use this in a good way.